# system running low graphics mode

Tags: 64-bit, radeon

My machine is AMD A8 / RADEON R5 graphics  with WIN 7 and I want to add ubuntu in it (aim is dual boot machine) 
when i tries to install ubuntu 17 its says System running low graphics mode

Comment: Run following command in tty mode      # sudo apt-get dselect upgrades